# dd using device label instead of device

Tags: linux, makefile, dd

I would like to use a device label instead of the device in a script that I am writing so I can use the script on multiple computers.

I want to change the line:

```
sudo dd if=$(TARGET) of=/dev/sdb
```

To

```
sudo dd if=$(TARGET) of=$(LABEL_NAME)
```

How do I do this? This script is part of a GNUMakefile.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible, DD expects a file.

Comment: Is there not some clever way to map a label back to a device? Some command I can run, provide it a label and get the device back, put this in a recipe etc.?

Comment: I think I answered my own question http://linux.die.net/man/8/findfs

Answer (score 0):

Solution to problem:

```
AR = ar
LD = ld
LL = ls -l
SRC = putstring.s
OBJ = $(SRC:%.s=%.o)
FILE = $(shell findfs LABEL=SEGATEUSB)

TARGET = putstring

all : $(OBJ) $(TARGET)

$(OBJ) : $(SRC)
        as -o $@ $<

$(TARGET) : $(OBJ)
        ld --oformat binary -Tlinker.ld -o $@ $^

install :
        sudo dd if=$(TARGET) of=$(FILE)

clean :
        rm -f $(OBJ) $(TARGET)
```